# Using multiple textures+filters in GLSL

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, mesa

I'm trying to render pointsprites in Opengl along a certain path. I define a sprite as a 2D texture and set it to use GL_NEAREST as the mag/min filter. I also define a 1D texture containing a few 2D coordinates (so that I only need 1 float per sprite to determine their screenspace location) which I set to GL_LINEAR.

However, when I run my program on my laptop it always uses the mag filter method of the sprite-texture and ignores the setting on the path-texture. My laptop runs Linux+mesa 9.2.1+Opengl 3.0 on an intel Iris Pro 5200. Everything works as expected on my desktop which runs Linux and uses the proprietary Nvidia driver with opengl 4.2.

The relevant code is

```
//A path "t -> (x,y)" along which we will place our sprites
v2f path[] = {{-0.5,0.5},
    {-0.5,-0.5},
    {0.5,-0.5},
    {0.5,0.5}};
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
 report(FAIL, "Couldn't activate texture!");

GLuint pathTex;
glGenTextures(1, &pathTex); //create a new texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, pathTex); //start using it as a 1D texture
//store the coordinates of path in the texture so that we can interpolate our path in the shader.
glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D,0,GL_RG32F, sizeof(path)/sizeof(v2f),0,GL_RG,GL_FLOAT,path); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);//We need these two lines
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);//because we don't have mipmaps.
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);//We want the path to be linearly filtered
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);//Set the min filter just to be safe.
if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
 report(FAIL, "Something went wrong setting up pathTex");
GLint uniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "pathTexture"); //locate the uniform
uniformLoc >= 0?glUniform1i(uniformLoc, 0):report(FAIL, "found uniform spriteTexture at %d", uniformLoc); //and set it to "0" because we're using GL_TEXTURE0
  if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
    report(FAIL, "Couldn't set uniform!");
  report(PASS, "Setup texture for path");

//create and set second texture
  rgba sprite[] = {{1.0,0,0,1},{0,1.0,0,1},{0,0,1.0,1},{1,1,0,1}}; //our sprite, a simple "red,green,blue,yellow" square.
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+1); //use texUnit 1 now.
  if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
    report(FAIL, "Couldn't activate texture!");
  GLuint spriteTex;
  glGenTextures(1, &spriteTex); //create a new texture
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteTex); //start using it as a 2D texture
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA, 2,2,0,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,sprite); //load the data again. 2x2 sprite.
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);//We need these two lines
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);//because we don't have mipmaps.
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);//We want our sprites to be filtered to
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);//the nearest pixel, not interpolated.
  if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
    report(FAIL, "Something went wrong setting up pathTex");
  uniformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "spriteTexture"); //locates and set the second sampler.
  uniformLoc >= 0?glUniform1i(uniformLoc, 1):report(FAIL, "found uniform spriteTexture at %d", uniformLoc);
  if(glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR)
    report(FAIL, "Couldn't set uniform!");
  report(PASS, "Setup texture for sprite");
```

And my vertex shader is

```
#version 130
uniform sampler1D pathTexture;
in float t;
void main(){
  gl_Position = texture(pathTexture, t);
}
```

and my fragment shader is

```
#version 130
uniform sampler2D spriteTexture;
out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
      outputColor = texture(spriteTexture, gl_PointCoord);
}
```

The whole code (single filed) I have pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/uQj3qA6F), and [here](http://imgur.com/a/eeku6) are screenshots of what I see on Nvidia and Intel respectively.

edit: I get the same results on Nvidia with a 3.0 context.

What can cause this?

Comment: If you are using OpenGL 4.x, you might consider using Sampler Objects to store the texture filter/wrap state. You can bind a sampler to texture unit 0 that uses nearest filtering and one to texture unit 1 that uses bilinear. Then instead of using the filter per-texture object, you can bind any texture you want to a unit and it will use the sampler's filter instead. It is really a much more elegant solution, as it basically turns texture objects into image stores and separates some of the states that really never belonged with them; it is such a good idea that D3D has done it for 10+ years :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice : ), but I've tried it using sampler objects too, however I get the same results.

Comment: Now that I understand what you are actually trying to do here, I feel obligated to point out that vertex texture fetches are very limited compared to fragment. Some hardware only supports a select few image formats in the vertex stage, linear filtering is not always hardware accelerated, anisotropic filtering **never** works in a vertex shader (it requires knowledge of a gradient / partial derivative which really makes no sense in the context of a per-vertex fetch) and mipmapping does not either. I have a feeling this is either a limitation of Mesa, the Iris hardware itself or possibly both.

Comment: That's a shame : (. I plan on making a tower-defence game similar in style to _Bloons Tower Defense_ eventually. I thought this would be a nice way to reduce the cpu-side work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call `glfwInit()` *before* any other GLFW functions

Same with `glewInit()`.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it, but unfortunately I still get the same results.